# Why the spinner doesnt work on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, css, spinner

My spinner works good on desktop browsers, and Android mobile browsers, but i can't see it on iPhone. Please help.

```
<svg class="spinner spinner-main " viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle>
      </svg>
```

```
.spinner {
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    
    & .path {
      stroke: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
      stroke-linecap: round;
      animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
    
  }
```

I tried to add -webkit- but it doesnt help

Comment: Please add the actual `@keyframe` animations to your code example